# Benefit of Google Highlighter

Tags: google-search-console, microdata

Has anyone used [Google's Data Highlighter](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2692911?hl=en) tool and compared the benefit of using it against adding structured data without using the Highlighter?

I've coded in [Schema](http://schema.org) tags within the markup of our site and have not used the Highlighter because we have a modal popup that displays on page load which I'm unable to dismiss in Google's Highlighter tool.  Just curious if it's worth disabling our popup to utilize the feature, or if it adds nothing since I've already done it in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

It adds nothing if you've already done it in the markup. Adding it on-page is vastly better because that data can then be consumed by all bots, whereas using the Data Highlighter only makes that data consumable to Google.